# mkdir not creating folder on new website (IIS)

Tags: php, iis, mkdir

I took over a project which had a few websites (`PHP` based) set up on its own server (using `IIS`). I needed to create some test systems up and created the new internal websites up with `IIS`.

I have come across a problem when I wanted to use `mkdir` on one of these new websites. The folders are not creating where I want them too. I am using the same code (Apart from the folder location) and nothing is happening where as on the websites which was previously set up, `mkdir` is working.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening? I haven't had much experience with `IIS` and guessing there could be a setting within here?

Comment: have you checked file ownerships and permissions yet?

Comment: permissions, permissions ... always check first permissions

Comment: make sure your have the permission to do it.

if you want to recursive make the folder use `mkdir -p /aaa/bbb/ccc`

Comment: Actually, just checked. I tried to make a folder on a different website (So, on Website B, run code to create a folder on Website A) which wasnt working. But I can create a folder on Website B (With the code on Website B.    However, Website A can create  a folder on both Website A & B.